# Find who created/last modified a given file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, file

I am using Ruby v2.2.3 on Windows 10.

I want to find out who created and who last modified a given file.  Is there a way to do this using Ruby?

Comment: by `who` you mean system user?

Comment: you can checkout this gem: https://github.com/thomasfl/filewatcher and you may need to check current logged in user and track it in the database.

Comment: one more example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914259/rails-detect-changes-to-files-programatically

Comment: Hint: [`File.stat`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/File.html#method-c-stat).

Comment: Yes, the system user.

Comment: I looked at the documentation for File.stat, but I don't see anything about the getting the system user.

Comment: Filewatcher seems to be about executing shell commands when files are updated, added, renamed or deleted.  But I want to know who changed a given file, even if that file was last changed years ago.

Comment: @Glenn File.stat will return a `uid` which you can then map to the system user.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't on the system I'm using.  File.stat(filename).uid always returns 0, for every file I tried.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to Windows, but at least on OSX (and I'd assume unix-lik OS's) `File.stat` and `Etc.getpwuid` will get you what you want.

```
> fstat = File.stat('../.bashrc')
=> #<File::Stat
 dev=0x1000004,
 ino=43746279,
 mode=0100644 (file rw-r--r--),
 nlink=1,
 uid=501 (philip),
 gid=20 (staff),
 rdev=0x0 (0, 0),
 size=1932,
 blksize=4096,
 blocks=8,
 atime=2016-09-29 11:19:45 -0700 (1475173185),
 mtime=2016-07-22 10:56:07 -0700 (1469210167),
 ctime=2016-07-22 10:56:07 -0700 (1469210167)>

> Etc.getpwuid(fstat.uid)
=> #<struct Etc::Passwd
 name="philip",
 passwd="********",
 uid=501,
 gid=20,
 gecos="Philip Hallstrom",
 dir="/Users/philip",
 shell="/bin/bash",
 change=0,
 uclass="",
 expire=0>
```